# view flip (calender flip) 3d animation android

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to have a calendar flip animation on a view. I have looked many examples but i got more confused.

I need to create an animation - Flip a view and show another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to implement a calendar flip animation in a flip card manner, you should try using this library.

`https://github.com/emilsjolander/android-FlipView`

It gives you a general way to do it. You can always extend it further to for finer implementations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard [`ViewFlipper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) component in Android. It extends `ViewAnimator` so you should be able to animate it if it doesn't do that by default.

Answer (score 0):

Just to notify that I've developed a new library [FlipView](https://github.com/davideas/FlipView) that includes basic flip animation and extends `ViewFlipper`. I mean a fully customizable library where you will be able to swap any kind of views and layouts with any kind of animation and shapes you desire, included the Gmail image flipping.

It differs from the library provided by danialzahid94. Mine is just a simple View not a ListView. By the way at time i write, ListView has been replaced by RecyclerView.

Please have a look.